# React.js: Wrapping one component into another

Tags: javascript, template-engine, composition, reactjs, transclusion

Many template languages have "slots" or "yield" statements, that allow to do some sort of inversion of control to wrap one template inside of another.

Angular has ["transclude" option](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements).

Ruby/Rails has [yield statement](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield). If React.js had yield statement, it would look like this:

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        before
          <yield/>
        after
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Wrapper><h1>content</h1></Wrapper>
    );
  }
});
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  before
    <h1>content</h1>
  after
</div>
```

Alas, React.js doesn’t have a `<yield/>`. How do I define Wrapper component to achieve the same output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the)

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Try:

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        before
          {this.props.children}
        after
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

See [Multiple Components: Children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children) and [Type of the Children props](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html) in the docs for more info.

Comment: Or you can use a Higher-Order Component :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31564812/82609

Answer (score 207):

## Using `children`

```
const Wrapper = ({children}) => (
  <div>
    <div>header</div>
    <div>{children}</div>
    <div>footer</div>
  </div>
);

const App = ({name}) => <div>Hello {name}</div>;

const WrappedApp = ({name}) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <App name={name}/>
  </Wrapper>
);

render(<WrappedApp name="toto"/>,node);
```

This is also known as `transclusion` in Angular.

`children` is a special prop in React and will contain what is inside your component's tags (here `<App name={name}/>` is inside `Wrapper`, so it is the `children`

Note that you don't necessarily need to use `children`, which is unique for a component, and you can use normal props too if you want, or mix props and children:

```
const AppLayout = ({header,footer,children}) => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="header">{header}</div>
    <div className="body">{children}</div>
    <div className="footer">{footer}</div>
  </div>
);

const appElement = (
  <AppLayout 
    header={<div>header</div>}
    footer={<div>footer</div>}
  >
    <div>body</div>
  </AppLayout>
);

render(appElement,node);
```

This is simple and fine for many usecases, and I'd recommend this for most consumer apps.

---

## render props

It is possible to pass render functions to a component, this pattern is generally called [`render prop`](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), and the `children` prop is often used to provide that callback.

This pattern is not really meant for layout. The wrapper component is generally used to hold and manage some state and inject it in its render functions.

Counter example:

```
const Counter = () => (
  <State initial={0}>
    {(val, set) => (
      <div onClick={() => set(val + 1)}>  
        clicked {val} times
      </div>
    )}
  </State>
);
```

You can get even more fancy and even provide an object

```
<Promise promise={somePromise}>
  {{
    loading: () => <div>...</div>,
    success: (data) => <div>{data.something}</div>,
    error: (e) => <div>{e.message}</div>,
  }}
</Promise>
```

Note you don't necessarily need to use `children`, it is a matter of taste/API.

```
<Promise 
  promise={somePromise}
  renderLoading={() => <div>...</div>}
  renderSuccess={(data) => <div>{data.something}</div>}
  renderError={(e) => <div>{e.message}</div>}
/>
```

As of today, many libraries are using render props (React context, React-motion, Apollo...) because people tend to find this API more easy than HOC's. [react-powerplug](https://github.com/renatorib/react-powerplug) is a collection of simple render-prop components. [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt) helps you do composition.

---

## Higher-Order Components (HOC).

```
const wrapHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Wrapper extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>header</div>
          <div><WrappedComponent {...this.props}/></div>
          <div>footer</div>
        </div>
      );
    }  
  }
  return Wrapper;
}

const App = ({name}) => <div>Hello {name}</div>;

const WrappedApp = wrapHOC(App);

render(<WrappedApp name="toto"/>,node);
```

An [Higher-Order Component / HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) is generally a function that takes a component and returns a new component.

Using an Higher-Order Component can be more performant than using `children` or `render props`, because the wrapper can have the ability to short-circuit the rendering one step ahead with `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Here we are using `PureComponent`. When re-rendering the app, if the `WrappedApp` name prop does not change over time, the wrapper has the ability to say "I don't need to render because props (actually, the name) are the same as before". With the `children` based solution above, even if the wrapper is `PureComponent`, it is not the case because the children element is recreated everytime the parent renders, which means the wrapper will likely always re-render, even if the wrapped component is pure. There is a [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements.html) that can help mitigate this and ensure a constant `children` element over time.

---

#### Conclusion

Higher-Order Components can give you better performance. It's not so complicated but it certainly looks unfriendly at first.

Don't migrate your whole codebase to HOC after reading this. Just remember that on critical paths of your app you might want to use HOCs instead of runtime wrappers for performance reasons, particularly if the same wrapper is used a lot of times it's worth considering making it an HOC.

Redux used at first a runtime wrapper `<Connect>` and switched later to an HOC `connect(options)(Comp)` for performance reasons (by default, the wrapper is pure and use `shouldComponentUpdate`). This is the perfect illustration of what I wanted to highlight in this answer.

Note if a component has a render-prop API, it is generally easy to create a HOC on top of it, so if you are a lib author, you should write a render prop API first, and eventually offer an HOC version. This is what Apollo does with `<Query>` render-prop component, and the `graphql` HOC using it.

Personally, I use both, but when in doubt I prefer HOCs because:

- It's more idiomatic to compose them (`compose(hoc1,hoc2)(Comp)`) compared to render props
- It can give me better performances
- I'm familiar with this style of programming

I don't hesitate to use/create HOC versions of my favorite tools:

- React's `Context.Consumer` comp
- Unstated's `Subscribe`
- using `graphql` HOC of Apollo instead of `Query` render prop

In my opinion, sometimes render props make the code more readable, sometimes less... I try to use the most pragmatic solution according to the constraints I have. Sometimes readability is more important than performances, sometimes not. Choose wisely and don't bindly follow the 2018 trend of converting everything to render-props.

Comment: This approach also makes it easy to pass the props down do children component (in this case Hello). From React 0.14.* onwards the only way to pass props to children components would be to use React.createClone, which might be expensive.

Comment: Question: The answer mentions "better performance" - what I don't understand: better compared to which other solution?

Comment: HOCs can have better performance compared to runtime wrappers, as they can short-circuit the rendering earlier.

Comment: When you use PureComponent, you don't need to return function any more. Just remove one wrap function:
```js
const wrapHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Wrapper extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>header</div>
          <div><WrappedComponent {...this.props}/></div>
          <div>footer</div>
        </div>
      );
    }  
  return Wrapper;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is like you took words from my month but you express them with greater talent 

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! The HOC-method was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Can I use HOC without wrapping the PureComponent in a function? Pass the WrappedComponent in props or something like that?

Comment: How can I make the `wrapHOC ` function in typescript with Generic types?

Answer (score 31):

In addition to Sophie's answer, I also have found a use in sending in child component types, doing something like this:

```
var ListView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var items = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
            return this.props.delegate({data:item});
        }.bind(this));
        return <ul>{items}</ul>;
    }
});

var ItemDelegate = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <li>{this.props.data}</li>
    }
});

var Wrapper = React.createClass({    
    render: function() {
        return <ListView delegate={ItemDelegate} data={someListOfData} />
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven’t seen any documentation on `delegate`, how did you find it?

Comment: you can add whatever props you want to a component and name them as you want, im using the this.props.delegate at row 4 but could just as well named it something else.