# React.js: can components from different hierarchies talk to each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is said in all React docs, that for component A to change state of component B, A has to be the owner of B or at least be on higher level in common hierarchy.

Say, I don't want A and B to be in the same component hierarchy. They are located in opposite sides of the page but I stil want them to interact.

Can I do this? Can I send some message from A to B or call some method or?...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating

Comment: You'll probably want [Scenario #3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21322402/1074592).