# reactJs : Communication between two different components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I want communication to happen between two independent components.

These components are not having any parent child relationship.

I found this piece of code.

I dont know how to use it
https://medium.com/react-zine/how-to-communicate-between-components-in-react-cc1ee986523a

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReactJS Two components communicating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Answer (score 13):

From the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html):

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

We use the PubSub pattern to attach global events, but as the docs say you can use many different arrangements.

**Example using [PubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS)**

Receiver component:

```jsx
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.token = PubSub.subscribe('MY TOPIC', this.subscriber)
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    PubSub.unsubscribe(this.token)
},
subscriber: function(msg, data) {
    console.log(msg, data)
    // set state etc...
})
```

Emitter:

```js
PubSub.publish('MY TOPIC', 'hello world!')
```