# Good approach to communicate between component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the good way to communicate between different components in React which are not children of one of them.

For example, this is my structure :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <SideBar title="My Sidebar"/>
                <SearchBox/>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class SideBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  Toggle = () => {
    this.refs.leftNav.toggle();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LeftNav ref="leftNav" className="sidebar">
        <MenuItem index={0}>A</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem index={1}>B</MenuItem>
      </LeftNav>
    );
  }
}

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.refs.leftNav.Toggle(); // Doesn't work obsviously...
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Hello
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I try to make Searchbox communicate with Sidebar because an element of SearchBox (in this case, the main `<div>`) has to toggle the `<SideNav>` when it gets clicked. However I don't see an easy way to do that and what is the right and recommended approach to do this kind of things ?

Comment: I think this answer gives the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21322402/759316

Comment: Thanks it's interesting ! but there is no way to have a more simple solution in this specific case ? (I just want to show a sidebar... it should be pretty straightforward)