# How can I call a component's method from another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal component with two methods that show/hide the modal. How can I call those methods from another component?

This is the code for the Modal:

```
// Dependencies
//==============================================================================
import React from 'react'
import Modal from 'boron/DropModal'

// Class definition
//==============================================================================
export default class RegistrationModal extends React.Component {
  showRegistrationModal() {
    this.refs.registrationModal.show()
  }

  hideRegistrationModal() {
    this.refs.registrationModal.hide()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal ref="registrationModal" className="modal">
        <h2>Meld je aan</h2>
        <button onClick={this.hideRegistrationModal.bind(this)}>Close</button>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - Call One Component Method From Another Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119537/reactjs-call-one-component-method-from-another-component)

Comment: You can check it  out https://github.com/burakozturk16/pigeon

Answer (score 1):

You can call a components method from the outside as long as you keep a reference to the component. For example:

```
let myRegistrationModal = ReactDOM.render(<RegistrationModal />, approot );
    // now you can call the method:
    myRegistrationModal.showRegistrationModal()
```

It's a bit cleaner if you pass a reference to the modal to another component, like a button:

```
let OpenModalButton = props => (
  <button onClick={ props.modal.showRegistrationModal }>{ props.children }</button>
);
let myRegistrationModal = ReactDOM.render(<RegistrationModal />, modalContainer );

ReactDOM.render(<OpenModalButton modal={ myRegistrationModal }>Click to open</OpenModalButton>, buttonContainer );
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/48169/

Answer (score 0):

You cant call it from another component, because its a method belong to `RegistrationModal` component, but you can refactor your code so you can call it

```
export function hideRegistrationModal() {
  console.log("ok");
}

export default class RegistrationModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal ref="registrationModal" className="modal">
        <h2>Meld je aan</h2>
        <button onClick={hideRegistrationModal}>Close</button>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

now you can call from anywhere but you need to import it first like this

```
import { RegistrationModal, hideRegistrationModal } from 'path to modal.js'
//       ^-- Component name  ^-- Method
```

Comment: Doing a `console.log` seems to work, but how would I access the `registrationModal` ref in the `RegistrationModal` class?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a parent component which will handle the communication between your modals.

A really great example and explanation can be found here: [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

This is a good approach because it keeps your components decoupled.