# Calling function from another component react

Tags: reactjs, callback

I make a onclick callback function in Top_Menu.jsx file and I want to create this function on other component. how can I do this..?

[image: [Top_Menu.jsx]]

[image: [Left_Menu.jsx]]

I make a onclick callback function in Top_Menu.jsx file and I want to create this function on other component. how can I do this..?

[image: Top_Menu.jsx]
[image: Left_Menu.jsx]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Try to create a [minimal runnable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can he you better.

Comment: Is it possible to make a question self-contained e.g. to include snippets of code you're referring to here, in the question body directly as a text, not images...

Comment: About your question, it looks like you need to pass the function as a prop in case when component is a parent to the other.

Comment: hi might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119537/reactjs-call-one-component-method-from-another-component