# Can not do multilingual website relying on React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, multilingual

I'm trying to make a multilingual SPA with React and to rely on React-Router.

Here is a simplified version of the entry file:

```
// define the routes for each language ..
const InnerRoutes = (
    <Route>
        <IndexRoute page="home" component={InnerPage}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="(:page)" component={InnerPage}></Route>
    </Route>
);

// define the routes for all the languages, using InnerRoutes .. 
const AllRoutes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App} language="bg">
            {InnerRoutes}
            <Route path="en" language="en">
                {InnerRoutes}
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

// and render our app ..
ReactDOM.render(
    AllRoutes,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

So, I have the `App` top-level component and the `InnerPage` component.

The issue is:

1. When navigation change happens - `InnerPage` updates and (eventually) re-renders.

Inside `InnerPage`:

2. I have access to the requested page via the `page` property.
3. Unfortunately - I don't have access to the `language` property.

And that's why `InnerPage` can't pull the data from an end point - it knows the `page`, but not the `language`.

Answer (score 0):

The router passes a `routes` prop to all route components, which is the set of matched routes. For example, on `/`, it would look something like this: `[{ path: '/', language: 'bg'}, { }, { page: 'home' }]`.

So, depending on how you want to deal with the cases of having none or multiple languages declared by different matched routes, you can do something like this:

```js
const lang = this.props.routes.reduce((lang, route) => { 
  return route.language || lang;
}, defaultLang);
```

which would prioritize the language given by inner routes.

Looking at your route config, there are two more things I should mention:

1. In your `InnerRoutes`, the page values for `<IndexRoute page="home" ... />` and `<Route path="(:page)" ... />` are exposed differently. The former is a prop on a route (like `language`) and can be accessed via `this.props.route.page`, while the latter is a URL param (`this.props.params.page`).
2. The English `<IndexRoute>` is not reachable, because the Bulgarian `:page` route comes before and matches as well. You can fix this by moving the English routes up.

Here's a jsbin demonstrating the points I mentioned: http://jsbin.com/siqake/5/edit?js,output

Comment: Well, the thing is that with the setup I've described - I have the `language` in the `App` component, but not in the `InnerPage` one. And about the `page` parameter - it's the vice versa. So - how can I have both - at least in the `InnerPage` component. ........... (Probably the routes setup is wrong ...)

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but isn't that what the `routes` prop solves? You get the same array of matched routes including their properties (`page`, `language`) in all your route components (`App`, `InnerPage`).

Comment: I went for the `routes` property, after I saw your comment, but it didn't work me also. Even if I loop the `routes` and check the stuff - the language one gets lost. ...... I opened an issue about it - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4176.

Comment: Hard to tell what went wrong without any additional code. I edited my answer above and included a jsbin. Hope this helps!