# Communicate between React Components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm just starting with React and it seems just beautifull to create user interfaces, however, I do have problem with communication between components.

I do have a very simple react component, representing a button:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class OfficeUIButton extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       active: false,
     };

     // Bind the event handlers.
     this.onMouseDownEventHandler = this.onMouseDownEventHandler.bind(this);
     this.onMouseUpEventHandler = this.onMouseUpEventHandler.bind(this);
   }

  onMouseDownEventHandler() {
    this.setState({
      active: true
    });
  }

  onMouseUpEventHandler() {
    this.setState({
      active: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return  <div className={"officeui-button" + (this.state.active ? ' active': '')} onMouseDown={this.onMouseDownEventHandler} 
                 onMouseUp={this.onMouseUpEventHandler}>
              <span className="officeui-button-label">{this.props.text}</span>
            </div>
  }
}
```

This component has a state property named `active`. Based on the state, an additional class is added to the button.

Let's assume that I have 2 of these `OfficeUIButton` components on my page, how can I, by clicking the first button, make the second button active?

This is just a dummy example, but I need this for example for a modal popup, or for disabling buttons based on a certain action.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Lift the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If multiple components somehow depend on each other, the state should be owned by one of their common ancestors.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need then the state in a parent component which will control your buttons. You can do something like :

Button component, where you pass **onClick** prop and **active** prop

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    render(){
    let disabled = this.props.active ? "disabled" : "";
    return(
        <div><button onClick={this.props.onClick} disabled={disabled}>Button</button></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in your parent you need to have a state which you will pass to the button components and onClick function:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

      this.state = {
        active: false
      }
    }

    handleClick(event){ 
      this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
            <Button active={this.state.active}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1443/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention, what if there are no parent elements?

Comment: Where would you than render the button component?

Comment: It is directly on the page, not inside another component. After some reading, I tought I need an event system such as Flux or is that a misunderstanding?

Comment: You can then maybe use redux or you need to have parent component if you want that children components communicate with each other. I'm not sure if it's possible otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dive deeper into Redux.

Answer (score 1):

You should in the higher component (let's asume for easy explanation that it is a page), where you will store a local store and where you will pass to each UIOFficeButton a function that would set this higher component state e.g. Button1Clicked on true, and also send that state to the other component.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          buttonOneClicked: false
        }
      }

handleClickButtonOne = () => this.setState({buttonOneClicked: true});

render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <OfficeUIButton onClick={this.handleClickButtonOne} />
               <OfficeUIButton disabled={this.state.buttonOneClicked} />
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Do not forget to actually handle that disabled and onClick props in your OfficeUIButton like in button

```
<button disabled={props.disabled} />
```

and do not use Span as a button.

Comment: I forgot to mention, what if there are no parent elements?

Comment: use redux for such stuff because if they are in the same level then there is imply now real connection between each other.