# Filter table data by date with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, filter, datatable, calendar

I am new to reactJs and trying to implement the below idea -

- A data table where data can be filtered by day of the month.
- A calendar which will show only days of a month in a row (pagination/tab like view):

  [image: like this image]
- Selecting each days will filter the data of the table on the page
- Next month can be selected by clicking on the month name appears on the end of the row and data will be filtered accordingly.

what I have tried -

- Use a react-bootstrap paginator
- Use a data table

I am finding it hard to figure our how can I implement the calendar and connect it as a filter with the data table. BTW, data of the table can be found from any database or some example data.

I hope I made it as clear as possible. Feel free to tell if I need to add something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 several components, for example `Filters` and `Data`, first will store your list of possible days, and month, on user select it will call some function, which will change props of the component `Data`, and in `ShouldComponentUpdate` of `Data` you can check was filters changed or no, and sort dates by the filter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating) is good answer with example, how it can be implemented in react, but also it would be more easy to use [`Redux`](http://redux.js.org/).

Hope this help.

UPD: Given example:

You can create your calender as empty html. Example of filtering :

ParentComponent

```
class CalendarContainer extends React.Component {
  construnctor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
       dataObjects = [..],
       datefilter = null
    } 
  }

  ShouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState) {
      return newState.filter != this.state.filter
  }

  handeUpdateFilter = (newFilter) => {
      this.setState({dateFiter : newFilter});
  }

  getFilteredDates = () => {
     return this.state.dataObjects.filter(x => x.date == this.state.dateFilter);
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <Filters filter={this.state.dateFilter}
          handeUpdateFilter = {this.chandeUpdateFilter}/>
       <DataTable dates={this.getFilteredDates()})
    }
}
```

And in filter component simply call `props.handeUpdateFilter(newFilter)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. right now I have seperate Pagination(that i wanted to reuse as calender, because I want 1 row calender) and Table component and can have the filter as a separate component , as far I understood. or can write the filter function inside calender so that when a date is being clicked, data inside table will filter according to it. But first of all I need to implement the calender in one row and similar to the image i have given earlier. How can I acieve that?