# React.js communiaction between components

Tags: reactjs

I have input component and checkbox component which both are close in other component which is repeat x times. How can I change value in input component when my checkbox will be selected?

```
resetValue(){
 this.props.value = 45;
 }

return( 
 <div> 
   <InputComponent value={this.props.value}/>
   <CheckboxComponent onChange={this.resetValue}/>
 </div>
)
```

Comment: possbile duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating

Comment: Never, ever, mutate the `props` directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)