# How to refresh data of one component from another component in react js

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm new to react js and creating one sample application with  and some basic CRUD operation.
I'm able to display a list, but I don't have any idea if I delete any record then how to refresh data grid.

Here is my code:

```
var DeleteRow = React.createClass({
    rowDelete: function (e) {
        console.log(this.props);
        var isConfirm = confirm("Are you sure want to delete this record?")
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Students/DeleteStudent',
                data: { id: this.props.data },
                success: function (data) {
                    // refresh the list data
                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return(            
              <button data={this.props.id} onClick={this.rowDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
         );
    },
});

var SudentList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var RowData = this.props.data.map(function(item){
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                 <td>{item.id}</td>
                 <td>{item.firstMidName}</td>
                 <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                 <td>{item.enrollmentDate}</td>
                 <td>Edit</td>
                 <td><DeleteRow data={item.id}/></td>
             </tr>
            );
          });

        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Fist Name</th>
                 <th>Last Name</th>
                 <th>Enrollment Date</th>
                 <th>Edit</th>
                 <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {RowData}
             </tbody>
         </table>            
      );
    }
});

var Gird = React.createClass({
    loadStudentsFromServer: function () {
        $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    items: data
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { items: [] };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadStudentsFromServer();
    },
    render: function () {

        var addBtnStyle = {
            margin:'10px',           
        }

        return (
             <div>
           <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right" style={addBtnStyle}>Add New</button>               
           <SudentList data={this.state.items} />                                                                    
         </div>
    );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Gird dataUrl='/Students/GetAllStudent' />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I want to refresh the data of `Gird` component from `DeleteRow` component on ajax success, how can I do that?.
I've gone through few questions on this site, but not luck so far.

Comment: what does the data in the success function of the `DeleteRow` contain? is it the list without the deleted row? or is it a message? or is it the deleted row id?

Comment: @MamdohSaraireh: It just a flag for testing, is record deleted or not! Nope it's not a list with updated data.

Comment: Use an anchor tag bound to each item with a callback in the ajax delete request that resets the state of the items.

Comment: @fungusanthrax: Can you please explain me with an example?

Comment: @HinaKhuman: I'm stuck with this same problem but in my case, I have a component 'A' and another Component 'B'(different file). So when I perform a post operation in A then B needs to refresh or update(say table needs to update). How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass a function to the `DeleteRow` component from the `Grid` component, so that when the delete is successful, you will update the list of items in `Grid`. Try something like this

```
var DeleteRow = React.createClass({
    rowDelete: function (e) {
        console.log(this.props);
        var self = this;
        var isConfirm = confirm("Are you sure want to delete this record?")
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Students/DeleteStudent',
                data: { id: this.props.data },
                success: function (data) {
                    // refresh the list data
                    self.props.onRowDelete(self.props.data)
                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return(
              <button data={this.props.id} onClick={this.rowDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
         );
    },
});

var SudentList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var RowData = this.props.data.map(function(item){
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                 <td>{item.id}</td>
                 <td>{item.firstMidName}</td>
                 <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                 <td>{item.enrollmentDate}</td>
                 <td>Edit</td>
                 <td><DeleteRow data={item.id} onRowDelete={self.props.onRowDelete}/></td>
             </tr>
            );
          });

        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Fist Name</th>
                 <th>Last Name</th>
                 <th>Enrollment Date</th>
                 <th>Edit</th>
                 <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {RowData}
             </tbody>
         </table>
      );
    }
});

var Gird = React.createClass({
    loadStudentsFromServer: function () {
        $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    items: data
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { items: [] };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadStudentsFromServer();
    },
    onRowDelete: function(id) {
      var items = this.state.items.filter(function(item, i) {
        return item.id !== id;
      })
      this.setState({items: items})
    },
    render: function () {

        var addBtnStyle = {
            margin:'10px',
        }

        return (
             <div>
           <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right" style={addBtnStyle}>Add New</button>
           <SudentList data={this.state.items} onRowDelete={this.onRowDelete}/>
         </div>
    );
    }
});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating) might be helpful as well

Comment: Hey, thanks, but facing an issue on this line `onRowDelete={this.props.onRowDelete}` it says `Cannot read property 'onRowDelete' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, that is because `this` is not defined in that scope, I have updated the answer to define `self` as `this` in the correct scope and use it later.

Comment: Did you put it as `{self.props.onRowDelete}`? Just make sure you have updated all of them

Comment: Sorry, did the same:) but issue is still there!

Comment: And the issue is at very first load, I'm not able to get list of students.

Comment: Opps, seems my mistake, sorry i forgot to add self at one place.

Comment: Oh dude, I've been checking the code for like 10 mins trying to figure it out. Glad it worked

Comment: I have one more query, Is it good way to go? and if I want to create some big application then I have to use `npm` and other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

i have one solution of your code, you can passing function `loadStudentsFromServer()` to component `DeleteRow` same like you passing `this.state.items` to component `SudentList`

you can change your code, the first one is here :

```
<SudentList data={this.state.items} loadStudentsFromServer={this.loadStudentsFromServer}/>
```

and then in your `SudentList` component you can add this function :

```
loadStudentsFromServer: function(){
        this.props.loadStudentsFromServer()
    }.bind(this),
```

and also change this one to passing your function to `DeleteRow` component :

```
<DeleteRow data={item.id} loadStudentsFromServer={this.props.loadStudentsFromServer} />
```

and just call the function if you success delete the data :

```
success: function (data) {
  // refresh the list data
  this.props.loadStudentsFromServer()
},
```

and this is the full code :

```
var DeleteRow = React.createClass({
    rowDelete: function (e) {
        console.log(this.props);
        var isConfirm = confirm("Are you sure want to delete this record?")
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Students/DeleteStudent',
                data: { id: this.props.data },
                success: function (data) {
                    // refresh the list data
                    this.props.loadStudentsFromServer()
                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return(            
              <button data={this.props.id} onClick={this.rowDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
         );
    },
});

var SudentList = React.createClass({
    loadStudentsFromServer: function(){
        this.props.loadStudentsFromServer()
    }.bind(this),
    render: function () {
        var RowData = this.props.data.map(function(item){
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                 <td>{item.id}</td>
                 <td>{item.firstMidName}</td>
                 <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                 <td>{item.enrollmentDate}</td>
                 <td>Edit</td>
                 <td><DeleteRow data={item.id} loadStudentsFromServer={this.props.loadStudentsFromServer} /></td>
             </tr>
            );
          });

        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Fist Name</th>
                 <th>Last Name</th>
                 <th>Enrollment Date</th>
                 <th>Edit</th>
                 <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {RowData}
             </tbody>
         </table>            
      );
    }
});

var Gird = React.createClass({
    loadStudentsFromServer: function () {
        $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    items: data
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { items: [] };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadStudentsFromServer();
    },
    render: function () {

        var addBtnStyle = {
            margin:'10px',           
        }

        return (
             <div>
           <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right" style={addBtnStyle}>Add New</button>               
           <SudentList data={this.state.items} loadStudentsFromServer={this.loadStudentsFromServer}/>                                                                    
         </div>
    );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Gird dataUrl='/Students/GetAllStudent' />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Hope it can help you, you can comment if have another error, thanks :)

Note : this code is re fetching your data from server after delete some data

Comment: Getting error `Cannot read property 'loadStudentsFromServer' of undefined`

Comment: sorry, i forget to `bind`ing the function

Comment: can you change this one please ? `loadStudentsFromServer: function(){
        this.props.loadStudentsFromServer()
    }.bind(this),`

Comment: Getting same same error at ajax success `success: function success(data) {
                    // refresh the list data
                    this.props.loadStudentsFromServer();
                }`

Comment: try to change this one `<DeleteRow data={item.id} loadStudentsFromServer={this.props.loadStudentsFromServer} />`

Comment: if you have same error, maybe you can bind the first loadloadStudentsFromServer function too, hope can solve :)