# How to pass array data to another page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a table in my main page lets say main.js, All I want is that every click in a row of the table I want it to display the data in my drawer. Anybody knows how to achieve this?. I followed a few examples but I can't get it right.

When the drawer is closed: 
[image: This a table when I close Drawer]

and I like to display it into this drawer.
[image]

But my Drawer and my Table are separate files so

Here's my code:

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return (
            <Table multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable} 
                onRowSelection={this._onRowSelection}>

                <TableHeader>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TableHeaderColumn style={tablestyles.columns.id}>
                            ID
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn style={tablestyles.columns.name}>
                            Name
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn style={tablestyles.columns.price}>
                            Price
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn style={tablestyles.columns.category}>
                            Category
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn style={tablestyles.columns.edit}>
                            Edit
                        </TableHeaderColumn>

                    </TableRow>

                </TableHeader>

                <TableBody>

                {Data.tablePage.items.map(item =>
                    <TableRow key={item.id}>

                        <TableRowColumn style={tablestyles.columns.id}>
                            {item.id}
                        </TableRowColumn>

                        <TableRowColumn style={tablestyles.columns.name}>
                            {item.name}
                        </TableRowColumn>

                        <TableRowColumn style={tablestyles.columns.price}>
                            {item.price}
                        </TableRowColumn>

                        <TableRowColumn style={tablestyles.columns.category}>
                            {item.category}
                        </TableRowColumn>

                        <TableRowColumn style={tablestyles.columns.edit}>
                            <Link className="button" to="/form">
                                <FloatingActionButton zDepth={0}
                                    mini={true} backgroundColor={grey200}
                                    iconStyle= {tablestyles.editButton}>
                                    <ContentCreate  />
                                </FloatingActionButton>
                            </Link>
                        </TableRowColumn>

                    </TableRow>

                ) }

            </TableBody>
        );
    }
};

export default CargoAddTable;
```

and I want to display the data in every click of the row into the white space inside the drawer.

and heres my code:

```
<Paper style={papers} zDepth={5}>
       {this.props.onRowSelection}
</Paper>
```

this gives me no error and no output.

Comment: By "another page" do you literally mean another page loaded from the server? Is this "another page" already loaded in another browser window?Or maybe you already have some sort of clientside routing.

Comment: ahm actually I already use react router,  and I want to fetch my selected row to my drawer. and how can it be done?.

Comment: I would suggest to add a parameter with comma separated id values.

Comment: So `onRowSelect`, you want to redirect to another page using React Router, and display the data that you have just displayed? Are you using anything like Redux? Where are you currently storing the data?

Comment: actually sir, the variable 'itemselected' I want the data inside that variable to pass it to my drawer. and my data is just a static just for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have a common parent for your table and drawer components, which will get data from the table and pass it to the drawer:

```
import Table from './Table';
import Drawer from './Drawer';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedRow: {
        name: "",
        price: "",
        category: ""
      }
    }
    this.getRow = this.getRow.bind(this);
  }

  getRow(selectedRow) {
    this.setState({ selectedRow });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table getRow={this.getRow}/>
        <Drawer row={this.state.selectedRow}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/04363w7qn

Or check [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Comment: yeah, your answer has some point but it didn't stack sir.  and if I select more than 1 it only displays one value.

Comment: It's just point how to send data between components, what should be displayed when you select few rows?

Comment: it should display all data of the selected column.

Answer (score 3):

As I can't see a parent-child relationship in your example (there is a react pure solution if this is the case) assuming that those two pages has no dependencies between them, and can be load asynchronously, you can use third party libraries like [react-pub-sub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) or [postal-react-mixin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postal-react-mixin), that allow you to **publish/subscribe** asynchronously to *topics*.

In your case, the topic should contain the object you want to share (*selectedItem*).

Then, you can publish that object from *CargoAddTable* component

```
_onRowSelection(key) {

     var itemselected = Data.tablePage.items[key];
     alert(key, itemselected);

     // Publish your object into 'Shared Item' topic.
     publish('Shared Item', itemSelected);
}
```

just to get it accesible from all the pages that are suscribed to that array. So, you can do it into your case *sample.js*

```
subscribe('Shared Item', callback);
```

and use the content from that suscription.

Comment: can I really use it locally?.

Comment: What do you mean. Of course! npm install -s react-pubsub, and then take a look at the links avobe that will guide you to integrate the plugin into your code.

Comment: I mean I use that kind of libraries like MQTT but I just use it to communicate between different platform, thank you for that sir.

Comment: You're welcome! What i propose it's It's the same concept, but between react components, so you can use it in yor pages

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating) to understand common situations between react components.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following example https://codesandbox.io/s/n2gqAxl7

Comment: thanks, sir but I think you misunderstand my question. I edited it to make it more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

Try accessing the props data as {this.props.children}.
Hopefully, it will work in your case.
[Reference Link](https://learn.co/lessons/react-this-props-children)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the index or id of the active row through react router's dynamic routing and recover the data (table row) from your database based on the index or id.