# Change attributes of initialized ReactJs components by their id

Tags: reactjs, components, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet for creating some polygons in **`map()`** function.

I need latter to access one of them and change some of the attributes, in example change **`fillCollor`** or **`fillOpacity`**

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className={'ZoneLayer'}>
                {
                    this.zones.map(zone => {
                        return (
                            <Polygon key={zone['id']}
                                     id={zone['id']}
                                     positions={zone['coordinates']}
                                     color={zone['available'] ? "#6dfdae" : "#dddddd"}
                                     fillOpacity={this.props.enableTransparency ? 0.4 : 1} >
                                <Tooltip direction={"top"} sticky={true} className={"zone-tooltip"} >
                                    <span>{zone['text']}</span>
                                </Tooltip>
                            </Polygon>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

How can I access one of the created components from another component?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I just updated question, How can I access one of the created components from another component?

Comment: How `this.zones` gets populated? Shouldn't be a prop of the component?

Comment: similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating?rq=1