# updating the DOM for unrelated components when using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have some navigation which is a react component. I then have a link in my content further down my page. When the link is clicked I want to add a CSS class to the navigation component.

They are completely separate components.

In the past I might use jQuery to target the nav, then use the addClass() function. I am struggling to figure this out in React.

Comment: Please take a look ate lifting up the state:   
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: It will make it **much** more likely you'll get useful answers if you include a [mcve] in the question demonstrating the problem/situation, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Probably not an exact duplicate but very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21285923

Answer (score 1):

for that, you have 2 options:

1. use a state management library such as Redux.
2. lifting up the state: 
   https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

In short, both of your components need to have the same father component, with a state, you will need to change the father component state, and the child component's props accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try the [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) ?

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.