# Access reactjs data through multiple classes

Tags: python, reactjs

I have a reactjs class called MyDictionary that renders data that a python file sends in. This class returns a dictionary structure. I want to access only a couple of elements from MyDictionary via a separate class, and a different set of elements also from MyDictionary, via a separate class. I tried `React.createElement(SomeOtherClass, {` as shown below, but this doesn't work... what am I missing?

```
class MyDictionary extends React.Component {
render() {
  return this.props.results.map((result, index) =>
    React.createElement(
      "div",
      { className: "col-sm-12" },
      React.createElement(SomeOtherClass, {
        key: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        index: result.index,
        activity: this.props.index + 1,
        images: this.props.image_labels
      })
    )
  );
 }
}
return MyDictionary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `this` operator inside the callback function is not what you expect.

The easiest way to resolve this is to create a var to `this` before your map call.

```
var _this = this;
```

Then use `_this` instead of `this` inside your callback.

You should also read up on javascript closures.

**Edit: render() should return one root element.**

```
class MyDictionary extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var _this = this;
    var children = this.props.results.map((result, index) =>
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "col-sm-12" },
        React.createElement(SomeOtherClass, {
          key: result.id,
          name: result.name,
          index: result.index,
          activity: _this.props.index + 1, // using _this
          images: _this.props.image_labels // using _this
        })
      )
    );
    return React.createElement("div", null, children);
  }
}
return MyDictionary;
```

Comment: So `React.createElement(SomeOtherClass, {` is the right way to link to multiple classes?

Comment: I did not notice this before, you need to also wrap your element inside one element, like a <div>.You are basically nesting `SomeOtherClass` inside your `MyDictionary` element. If it makes sense, then it should be fine. (If you think in terms of HTML elements, MyDictionary is a <div> that contains multiple elements.

Comment: Ok, this is helpul, ty. I guess the question that still stands is... can I access the values of the children from MyDictionary and render them through another class?  Or multiple classes? How would I do that? I'm pretty lost and I've been trying to figure this out for days...

Comment: like... why can't the elements be accessed thorough MyDictionary.this.props.children?

Comment: Here's a good answer to what I think you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating