# Use a child's method in a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

NavigationComponent - this is my navigation. I want the button clicked here to fire up a method from the child.

```
class NavigationComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
                this.setState(
                    {
                        user: user
                    }, () => this.props.checkUserState(this.state.user)
                );
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Navbar>
                        <Navbar.Header>
                            <Navbar.Brand>
                                <Link id='home' to="/">UczIchApp</Link>
                            </Navbar.Brand>
                        </Navbar.Header>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer id='about' to='/about'>
                                <NavItem>O nas</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            {
                                this.state.user ?
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <LinkContainer id="questions" to='/questions'>
                                            <NavItem>Zadania</NavItem>
                                        </LinkContainer>
                                        <NavItem onClick={Want to use it here}>Wyloguj się</NavItem>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                    :
                                    <NavItem onClick={And here}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
                            }
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutComponent}/>
                        <Route exact path="/questions" component={QuestionsComponent}/>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}/>
                        <Route path='/question/:id' component={QuestionComponent}/>
                    </Switch>
                </React.Fragment>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

LogoutComponent - I want a method from this component to be fired up

```
export default class LogoutComponent extends react.Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
        console.log('tada');
    }

    logout() {
        console.log('got here');
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({
                    user: null
                }, function () {
                    this.props.checkUserState(this.state.user)
                });
            });
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to use the logout() function when the button on the navbar is clicked. The problem is I have no idea how to reference it.

I tried something like this `LogoutComponent.logout`, but no luck. If it's not possible, how could I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Comment: This question asks about siblings. I'm talking about parent - child relation

Comment: Calling a method of a child component is not the React way.

Comment: So how should I get going about it?

Comment: Note that the two `<NavItem>`s are siblings. The linked question, **and more importantly its answers**, is a good place to start.

Comment: NavItem is a Bootstrap component. How can I use them for my purposes?

Comment: @alex.iron take a look at the first answer. It explains different ways to deal with components communication. The scenario a is about parent-child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using **React refs**, and a **method** on the child component.

parent.js

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.child_ref = null;
}

createChildRef(DOMElement) {
  this.child_ref = DOMElement;
}

respondToSomeEvent() {
  if (this.child_ref) {
    this.child_ref.somePublicMethod();
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <ChildComponent ref={this.createChildRef} />
  )
}
```

child.js

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  somePublicMethod() {
    // The parent can call this method through the React ref
  }
}
```

Sometimes it is necessary to do this, based on the architecture of your application, but you should look into passing around an **EventEmitter** instance instead, so that your components can respond to changes outside of state that is stored in React.

Comment: What is `DOMElement` here?

Comment: It’s an instance of the rendered child React component on the page: you can use both DOM methods on it, as if it were an HTML element, and you can call methods from the React component class that generated it.