# React JS: How to hide/show tabs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide/show some tabs in a different file. We have a modal with tabs, and some of the tabs should hide while clicking on radio buttons from another file which is another component. I mean that those components is in different files.

My question is how do I pass data or functions from one file to another file? I will need to do this with my onChange for the radio buttons. I am using the Tabs from react-bootstrap.

I hope some of you know some examples of how to do it?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

In tabs.js

```
export default class ArchiveForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static defaultProps = {
    onChange() {}
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bindings
    this.handleTabChange = this.handleTabChange.bind(this);

    // Child refs
    this.childrenForms = {};
    this.state = {
      key: 1
    };
  }

  handleTabChange(key) {
    this.setState({key});
  }

  handleHideTabs(key) {
    const {data} = this.props;
    if (data.Type === 0) {
      this.change = key === 2 && 3;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {data, archive, groups, users} = this.props;
    const {key} = this.state;
    console.log('markers tab', data);

    if (data.Type === 0) {
      this.change = false;
    } else {
      this.change = true;
    }

    return (
      <Tabs
        activeKey={key}
        onSelect={this.handleTabChange}
        id="workflow-edit-form"
        bsStyle="pills"
        animation={false}
      >
        <Tab eventKey={1} title="General">
          <Row>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <Identification
                {...data}
                ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.Identifications = instance; }}
                change={event => this.handleHideTabs(event)}
              />
              <Condition
                {...data}
                ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.Conditions = instance; }}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <Display
                {...data}
                ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.Displays = instance; }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Tab>
        {this.change && (
          <Tab eventKey={2} title="Action">
            <Row>
              <Col sm={12}>
                <Action
                  {...data.Action}
                  ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.Actions = instance; }}
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Tab>)}
        {this.change && (
          <Tab eventKey={3} title="Notification">
            <Row>
              <Col sm={6}>
                <Notification
                  {...data.NotificationSettings}
                  ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.Notifications = instance; }}
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Tab>)}
        <Tab eventKey={4} title="Archive filter">
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              {/* <ArchiveFilter
                {...data.ArchiveFilter}
                archive={archive}
                ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.ArchiveFilters = instance; }}
              /> */}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={5} title="Access list">
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <AccessList
                properties={data.AccessList.Members}
                groups={groups}
                users={users}
                ref={instance => { this.childrenForms.MemberList = instance; }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

In the file where the radio button is. Identification.js

```
export default class extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRadioChange = this.handleRadioChange.bind(this);
    const {Name, Description, Type, Modes, DisplayType, Position} = props;
    this.state = {Name, Description, Type, Modes, DisplayType, Position};

    this.translations = {
      identification: LocalizationService.get('userManagement', 'identification'),
      name: LocalizationService.get('userManagement', 'name'),
      description: LocalizationService.get('userManagement', 'description'),
      type: LocalizationService.get('management', 'type'),
      standard: LocalizationService.get('management', 'standard'),
      extended: LocalizationService.get('management', 'extended')
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleRadioChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      Type: parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {Name, Description, Type} = this.state;
    return (
      <form className="modal-container">
        <h4>{this.translations.identification}</h4>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel className="input-label">{this.translations.name}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            className="modal-inputs"
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
            value={Name}
            data-name="Name"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel className="input-label">{this.translations.description}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            className="modal-inputs"
            placeholder="Description"
            type="text"
            value={Description}
            data-name="Description"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel className="input-label">
          {this.translations.type}
        </ControlLabel>
        <FormGroup className="condition-radio-buttons">
          <Radio name="radioGroup10" defaultChecked={Type === 0} value={0} onChange={props.change}>
            {this.translations.standard}
          </Radio>
          {' '}
          <Radio name="radioGroup10" defaultChecked={Type === 1} value={1} onChange={this.handleRadioChange}>
            {this.translations.extended}
          </Radio>
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

And yes I get my data from API! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MTCoster I have been trying to get the key from the Tabs. The tabs has a attribute which is called "eventKey".

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your code to the question?

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: @MTCoster I have edited now and my code is there.

Comment: @MTCoster I have tried to use some other way, but in identification file the onChange says props is not used on the first radio button.

Comment: You need to share the state between components. Check this answer to get an idea what are the available options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563614/8164758

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov Thank you! I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have come across is normal and everyone runs into it at some point during a projects development cycle.

One of the possible solutions would be to move the state up to a component that's a parent of both of the components that need to share the data, and then pass the state down as a prop to both components.

If that's an ugly solution for you, your best option is to use a state management library. The most popular ones are [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I have done this solution and it works a little. I tried to share the same method and tried out with console.log with a message and it does show up while clicking on the radio button. The method is located in the tabs.js :) but need to find the way to make the "key" state work and hide it.

Comment: or React's Context API...its much more convenient than redux (also requires no dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

This issue I have solved using tabClassName='d-none'.

```
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="text" id="text">
          <Tab eventKey="text" tabClassName={!this.state.visual ? 'd-none' : 
            ''} title="Text">
            <Text user={this.state.id} getPostLength={this.getPostLength} />
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="visual" tabClassName={!this.state.visual ? 'd-none' : 
            ''} title="Visual">
            <Visual user={this.state.id} getPostLength={this.getPostLength} />
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="video" tabClassName={!this.state.video ? 'd-none' : 
             ''} title="Video">
            <Video user={this.state.id} getPostLength={this.getPostLength} />
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="audio" title="Audio">
            <Audio user={this.state.id} tabClassName={!this.state.audio ? 'd- 
             none' : ''} getPostLength={this.getPostLength} />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
```