# How use some props on other components Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component

I mapped through the list of Movies(Posters), i have button (watch) on each poster, once you click the button watch it will take you to another component (watch). How do i pass the individual poster props from Poster component to the watch component on button click.

```js
{this.state.Poster.map(poster =>
          <Col md="3 " className="" >
            <Card className="card-user card-transparent">
              <CardImg top src={`/files/${poster.filename}`}></CardImg>
                <CardText className="py-3 px-3">
                  <div className="card-description">
                  <h6 className="display-5  text-center">{poster.metadata.name}</h6>
                  <p className="text-center">{poster.metadata.Description}</p>
                  </div>
                  </CardText>
                <CardFooter>
                  <div className="button-container  py-3"><a href="watch">
                    <Button className="btn-fill btn-movie " color="primary" >
                      Watch
                    </Button></a>
                  </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            )}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `react-router | react-router-dom` in `v4`  , you can do it in either of these ways:

**A**

1. Replace  with

```
<Link
  className="btn btn-primary" // some bootstrap class 
  to={{
    pathname: "/watch",
    state: { posterId: poster.id } // I am assuming  post has id
  }}
/>
```

2. in `WatchComponent`

```
class WatchComponent extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
   const { posterId } = this.props.location.state;
   //make ajax request to the server and get poster details 
   //promise resolve, set response into state 
   // this.setState({ poster: res.json()})

 }
 render() {
   const { poster } = this.state;
   return (
     // render poster details here.
   )


 }
}
```

**Or** 
You can simply do this

```
<Link
  className="btn btn-primary" // some bootstrap class 
  to={`/watch/${posterId}`} // provided that Route of WatchComponent is defined as (URL parameter) <Route path="watch/:posterId" component={WatchComponent} />
/>
```

then in WatchComponent you do

```
class WatchComponent extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
   const { posterId } = this.props.macth.params;
   //make ajax request to the server and get poster details 
   //promise resolve, set response into state 
   // this.setState({ poster: res.json()})

 }
 render() {
   const { poster } = this.state;
   return (
     // render poster details here.
   )


 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try doing that

Comment: Another way, without react-router-domm could be making Card as component and attach a callback, say it `getId` to it, then fire the later whenever a button is press within and pass back  `postId` to parent component which will re-render and pass down postId to  `WatchComponent`. This requires component life cycle such as componentDidUpdate and more tweaks.

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji Hello, was this issue fixed?

Comment: Please could you provide example for me?