# React Apollo: Update lists cache (with variables) when new item is added

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to update a list of items (in the cache). When a new item is created with `react-apollo`.

The `<CreateItemButton />` component is (in my case) not nested within `<ListItems />` component. From what I can figure out, I need to update the cache via the update function in my createItemButton `<Mutation />` component.

The problem is when I try to `store.readQuery({query: GET_LIST_ITEMS, variables: ???})` to get the current list of items (to append my recently created item), this can have variables/filters (for pagination, sorting etc.).

How do I know what variable to pass to the `store.readQuery` function, is there a sort of "last used variables" around this, or do you have any other suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I suggest adding code snippets and examples. Perhaps a link to a demo/example that people can use to help answer your question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating?rq=1) might help. But examples and code snippets are best practice when asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Apollo issue and the team is working on it. The current options you have can be found [in this medium post](https://medium.com/@martinseanhunt/how-to-invalidate-cached-data-in-apollo-and-handle-updating-paginated-queries-379e4b9e4698).

It is also an issue with deleting/updating an item when you have it in a list with filters or pagination.

Here is a reference of [an opened issue on Github about it](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but a bit hacky to access the `cache.watches` `Set`? :S

The trick is to access the cache's variables for a given query, save it and perform a refetch with the given query variables. In my case after creation of an item:

```
export const getGraphqlCacheVariables = (queryName, cache) => {
  if (cache.watches) {
    const watch = [...cache.watches].find(w => !!w.query[queryName]);

    if (watch) {
      return watch.variables;
    }
  }
};
```

The `mutation` `update` function:

```
let variables;

const update = (cache, { data }) => {
  if (data && data.createTask && data.createTask.task) {
    variables = getGraphqlCacheVariables('GetTasks', cache);
  }
}
```

And the `refetchQueries` function:

```
const refetchQueries = () => {
      if (variables && Object.keys(variables).length > 0) {
        return [{ query: GET_TASKS, variables }];
      }
      return [];
}
```

Bot the update and refetchQueries functions should have access to the `variables` variable

The benefit compared to the solution in the [Medium article](https://medium.com/@martinseanhunt/how-to-invalidate-cached-data-in-apollo-and-handle-updating-paginated-queries-379e4b9e4698), is that you're not deleting the cached data for a given query (GET_TASKS) with different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo now provides a new directive that allows ignoring of some variables when querying the cache. Check it [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/#the-connection-directive). I've used it to ignore my changing pagination params.