# Call value used by reusable functional component in another function in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to coding let alone, react native. I'm trying to find a way to get values received by a reusable functional component using props in another function of another page, is there a way for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.