# dropdown don't close when I click on another

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Here I have 3 dropdowns.
When click outside all of 3 dropdowns are closed normally but when I click on the other dropdown the others remain opened when already opened.
The intended behavior is that even when I click on other dropdown it should close whatever dropdown already opened.
How to achieve this?

This is a the demo I'm working on:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mxncy7?file=src%2Findex.css

Comment: As I could check, you have to notify the other Apps components you clicked over and propagate them to close, because is interacting without being "outside"

Comment: How to achieve that please?, I tried already without succeeding, they're all the same dropdown, how to distinguish the difference between them?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563614/6158032 , also I think you have to create another component to wrap those dropdowns

Comment: Appreciate your help! but the solution below is very simple.

Comment: Yes sir, @the-hutt  nail it the situation, with a master class of events of javascript :)

Comment: Though the e.stopPropagation is not recommended way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onBlur` event to close the dropdown:

```js
function App() {
  ...
  const handleOnBlur = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsOpenDropdown(false);
  };
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dropdown-wrapper"
        tabIndex="0" 
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      >
        <div
          className="dropdown-btn"
          onClick={handleClickDropdownButton}
        >
   ...
   );
}
```

Full [demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mxncy7-tq9c7v?file=src%2FApp.jsx).

Comment: The dropdown close is ok but I can't select any option now.

Comment: :) Setting `tabIndex` and `onBlur` on `dropdown-wrapper` fixes the issue. Check the latest code.

Comment: great!, it works as charm :) thanks for help!

Comment: Can I do the same thing without stop propagation please?

Comment: It also works without stop propagation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mxncy7-tq9c7v . I added that as a precaution to avoid any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Its because its set to handle clicks outside that is the background and the drop down list is a button.