# Getting DOM node from React child element

Tags: reactjs

Using the `React.findDOMNode` method that was introduced in v0.13.0 I am able to get the DOM node of each child component that was passed into a parent by mapping over `this.props.children`.

However, if some of the children happen to be React Elements rather than Components (e.g. one of the children is a `<div>` created via JSX) React throws an invariant violation error.

Is there a way to get the correct DOM node of each child after mount regardless of what class the child is?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`this.props.children` should either be a ReactElement or an array of ReactElement, but not components.

To get the DOM nodes of the children elements, you need to clone them and assign them a new ref.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (element, idx) => {
        return React.cloneElement(element, { ref: idx });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can then access the child components via `this.refs[childIdx]`, and retrieve their DOM nodes via `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[childIdx])`.

Comment: Doesn't this break any existing `ref` that was assigned to the children in the parent? In other words if you had `<div ref="a" />` as your children, wouldn't this break any references to `refs.a` because you overwrite it to `idx`?

Comment: It does. If you wish to preserve refs, you should use [callback refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute). `{ ref: node => this.node = node; element.ref(node); }`

Comment: how do you expose the ref from a higher order component? For example, export default withInputMask(withRequired(withReadOnly(withMinMax(withHidden(TextInput)))));  if I want access to a dom element in TextInput from withInputMask, how would i achieve it? I have tried callback refs but its not made available in withInputMask. Its undefined.

Comment: @monkeyjumps
   `componentDidMount() {`
       `let outtermostDomNodeOfHoc = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))`
   `}`

Comment: Note that `this.props.children` can contain pure text nodes (as it sometimes did in my case when designing a flexible `<Tooltip>` component that could be wrapped around any valid jsx). This will cause an error in `React.cloneElement(element)`. As such, it's worthwhile to check `React.isValidElement(element)` and/or `typeof element === 'string'`.

Comment: Worth noting that this does not work for functional components.

Answer (score 18):

This may be possible by using the refs attribute.

In the example of wanting to to reach a `<div>` what you would want to do is use is `<div ref="myExample">`.  Then you would be able to get that DOM node by using `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myExample)`.

From there getting the correct DOM node of each child may be as simple as mapping over `this.refs.myExample.children`(I haven't tested that yet) but you'll at least be able to grab any specific mounted child node by using the ref attribute.

Here's the official [react documentation on refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) for more info.

Comment: Worked for me, but the api is now `ReactDom.findDOMNode(..)`

Comment: excellent solution when going down the anti-pattern path of setting components in state (the solution if you have this is to not do this pattern and conditionally render it by a stateful variable)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to access any DOM element simply add `ref` attribute and you can directly access that element.

```
<input type="text" ref="myinput">
```

And then you can directly:

```
componentDidMount: function() 
{
    this.refs.myinput.select();

},
```

Their is no need of using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`, if you have added a `ref` to any element.

Comment: Note that you don't need findDOMNode only if you have added a ref to a DOM element (e.g. <div ref="myRef" />). You do need it if you use ref on a React component node (e.g. <MyComponent ref="myRef" />. In the first case this.refs.myRef is the DOM node, while in the second it's the React component instance.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the new [React ref api](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```
function ChildComponent({ childRef }) {
  return <div ref={childRef} />;
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  myRef = React.createRef();

  get doSomethingWithChildRef() {
    console.log(this.myRef); // Will access child DOM node.
  }

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent childRef={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most up to date answer as of Nov 2018.  And also simplest.

Comment: How do you adapt this for unknown number of `children`?

Answer (score 5):

`React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myExample)` mentioned in another answer has been deprectaed.

use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` from `'react-dom'` instead

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
let myExample = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myExample)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy way using the new callback refs. You can just pass a callback as a prop to the child component. Like this:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this)
  }

  setRef(node) {
    this.childRef = node
  }

  render() {
    return <Child setRef={ this.setRef }/>
  }
}

const Child = ({ setRef }) => (
    <div ref={ setRef }>
    </div>
)
```

Here's an example of doing this with a modal:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    }
    this.open = this.open.bind(this)
    this.close = this.close.bind(this)
    this.setModal = this.setModal.bind(this)
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }

  close(event) {
    if (!this.modal.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ open: false })
    }
  }

  setModal(node) {
    this.modal = node
  }

  render() {
    let { modalOpen } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.open }>Open</button>
        {
          modalOpen ? <Modal close={ this.close } setModal={ this.setModal }/> : null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Modal = ({ close, setModal }) => (
  <div className='modal' onClick={ close }>
    <div className='modal-window' ref={ setModal }>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: This is really slick. I looked around for a while on how to do this. It's simple, works like a charm and doesn't involve using hacky React.findDOMNode business.

Comment: Regarding your edit suggestions those only work if you're using ES7, which I haven't configured webpack for yet.

Comment: This way people who are using older syntax will still be able to figure out this answer.

Comment: True and those that use this will hopefully see around it. (For context: I suggested using an arrow function to bind `this` instead of doing it in the constructor.)

As a follow-up, I did find that another way to gain access to a child ref, I documented as a solution below.