# Expose child component functions to parent with ref using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This link describes how you can set a ref on a component and call its functions from a parent: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html

How do i achieve this when i'm using react-router and the component I want to ref is a route and the parent is the root component?

Answer (score 1):

This works:
Give `<RouteHandler/>` a ref, like this: `<RouteHandler ref="routerHandler"/>`

Then call like this:
`this.refs.routerHandler.refs.__routeHandler__.someFunctionOnActiveRoutesHandler()`

Comment: Any idea what the react-router 2.x equivalent of this is?

Comment: React Router 2.0 gives you this.props.children. Use this approach to get a ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568721/getting-dom-node-from-react-child-element, and this approach to call a function: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html. Keep in mind this is an anti-pattern.