# Getting DOM node from React child element without ReactDOM.findDOMNode

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am wondering how I can find the DOM node of a React child. This question has been asked before, however in every solution I can find (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568721/getting-dom-node-from-react-child-element)), the accepted answer makes use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`. I don't consider this to be an ideal solution since use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` is discouraged, and it may be [deprecated in the future](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220).

If have looked into creating a new ref with `React.createRef()` from `cloneElement`, but this doesn't seem to provide a way of accessing `getBoundingClientRect()` which I require.

ie.

```
// in constructor
this.childElement = React.createRef();

...

const newChild = React.cloneElement(
      childElement,
      { ref: this.childElement }
    );
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this without `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with getting the DOM node of child via `<div ref={node => this.node = node} />` for example?

Comment: In my case, yes. I have a wrapper component which needs to be able to assign a ref to any Component or element passed as `props.children`.

Comment: Can you iterate the children and assign a ref to each?

Comment: In my case the wrapper should only ever take in one child, so I do `const childElement = React.Children.only(this.props.children);`

As shown above, this element is cloned and I try to assign a ref (but obviously the node doesn't seem to work as intended since I cannot call `getBoundingClientRect`). This should effectively be the same as iterating through and assigning refs.