# React - access component library's child DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a component library, which renders an `input` field nested within several `div` elements

```
<ComponentLibrary />
```

This component library renders a tree similar to the one below:

```
<div className={outerDiv}>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />  // This the element I'm trying to access
  </div>
</div>
```

I built a custom component which wraps the `ComponentLibrary` similar to below:

```
<MyCustomComponent>
  <ComponentLibrary />
</MyCustomComponent>
```

I don't have access to modify the component library, but I need to access it's `input` field within my component.

```
const MyCustomComponent = (props) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  return (
    {React.cloneElement(props.children, {
      ref: inputRef // This ofcourse references the 'outerDiv'
    }}
  );
}
```

Some possible relevant notes, when I `console.log(props.children)`. While the component is react element, the type is a forward ref.

```
> children:
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
  ref: null
  > type: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)}
```

Below are a few more attempts I made:

```
{React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
   console.log(child) // Only logs the Component element. No reference of DOM nodes
}
```

The closest I've gotten is by using the `inputRef` I created in the 4th code block above.

```
console.log(inputRef.current)
// Logs `outerDiv` element

console.log(inputRef.current.children[0]?.children[1]?.children[1])
// Returns the right element, but an absolute mess. Is this my best solution?
```

Comment: What is the component library you're using?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I'm using an internal component library built by a team in my company, who works independently from mine.

Comment: What is the documented interface of `ComponentLibrary`? It would be preferable to use that than to use React internals in such a way that is likely to break the next time `ComponentLibrary`'s implementation updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be understanding this wrong here, but from reading your question I assume `ComponentLibrary` looks something like this:

```
const ComponentLibrary = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
));
```

I'm assuming this because the `type` prop of `props.children` has a value of

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)
```

In replicating your `MyCustomComponent` setup

```
const MyCustomComponent = (props) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputRef.current); 
  });

  return React.cloneElement(props.children, {
    ref: inputRef,
  });
};
```

`inputRef.current` logs out the following element:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use the `children` property to find a child element and chain this to eventually get the input element as you did in your example, but you could also use [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and target the element by its attributes and/or type.

For example:

```
console.log(inputRef.current.querySelector('input[type="text"]'));
```

Comment: Much better solution. Thank you. I honestly didn't even think about doing this!

Comment: So, since the ComponentLibrary is a forwardedRef. Is there a better / preferred way of accessing it or it's children, instead of `props.children` ?

Comment: Also, thank you for bearing with me. I realize that was a lot of post, for a one line solution. But its extremely helpful that you broke down the various code blocks and either reiterated on the information I provided or gave context to the questions I asked. So cheers for your patience and detail

Comment: I'm not sure about a better way. You could use `children` if you use destructuring in the function arguments `({children})` instead of `(props)`, but that's a pretty insignificant change. You could also render `ComponentLibrary` inside `MyCustomComponent` directly without using props and attach the ref directly. You would lose some flexibility in terms of wrapping other similar types of components compared to use `children` though. For an overview of approaches of getting a dom node from child elements you could look at...

Comment: ...[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568721/getting-dom-node-from-react-child-element?answertab=oldest#tab-top)