# What is the correct PropTypes for component or element

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a component that I want the element type to be configurable.

```
const Col = ({ containerElement, children }) => {
  return (
    <containerElement>
      {children}
    </containerElement>
  );
};

Col.defaultProps = {
  containerElement: 'div'
};
```

So container element could either be as in the defaultProps above or it could be a component.

```
<Col containerElement={<MyComponent} />
```

I can't get the `propTypes` to validate, I have tried this:

```
Col.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  containerElement: PropTypes.oneOf([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.element
  ]),
```

But it does not validate correctly.

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `componentClass` of value `div`
>   supplied to `Col`,

Comment: What exactly are you passing to the component? If the value is really an element, then you cannot use it as `<containerElement>` anyway. `<containerElement>` is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement('containerElement', ...)`. Even if it is a string, `'containerElement'` will be passed to `React.createElement`, not the *variable* `containerElement`. Before worrying about the validation error I would make sure the code itself produces the correct result (i.e. works correctly).

Comment: Agree with @FelixKling. You'll want to instantiate the <Element> via something like `const ContainerElement = containerElement.inner`. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/504018

Comment: @FelixKling Small question, here: "Even if it is a string, 'containerElement' will be passed to React.createElement, not the variable containerElement" -- by "not the variable containerElement" you refer to the constructor function of the component to which containerElement should refer right?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: Yes. I guess I mixed runtime vs compile time terminology here. `<containerElement>` becomes `React.createElement('containerElement'...)`, not `React.createElement(containerElement, ...)`. So during transformation, a string literal is created, not a variable and at runtime a string value is passed, not the value of the variable.

Comment: @FelixKling it seems it also has to do with `<containerElement>` vs `<ContainerElement>`.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: Yes. Lower case name becomes a string literal and upper case name becomes a variable reference in the transpiled code.

Answer (score 8):

Now with prop-types **15.7.0** released you can do:

```
Col.propTypes = {
  ...
  containerElement: PropTypes.elementType,
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and `element`❓

Comment: element is for an instance (`<Foo />`), elementType is for a component class (`Foo`).

Answer (score 3):

**There is some wrong stuffs in your code:**

you put a **non-capitalize react component** (which exists in the element's props):

```
const Col = ({ containerElement, children }) => {
  return (
    <containerElement>    // <---this should start with uppercase letter
      {children}
    </containerElement>
  );
};

Col.defaultProps = {
  containerElement: 'div' // this should be Componenet type not string
};
```

**React Components always should start with capital letter** else it will be conflicted with html elements

```
Col.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  containerElement: PropTypes.oneOf([ // you should use PropTypes.oneOfType
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.element
  ])
```

*PropTypes.oneOf* is used to indicate that the value should be in the array argument.

*PropTypes.oneOfType* is used to indicate that the value's type shoudl be in the array argument.

if we say `Component.propTypes = { theme: PropTypes.oneOf(["dark", "light"])}` we indicate that the value of theme props **should be either dark or light**.

if we say `Component.propTypes = { data: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number])}` we indicate that type of the data prop **should be string or number**.

before i show you a demo code that i wrote **you should know the difference between component and component element**. if you know so you can skip this part:

**component** is: `Component` and it's type is *PropTypes.elementType*.
**component element** is `<Componenet />` or `<Component>...</Component>` and it's type is *PropTypes.element*.

*here is my demo code if you have any propblem or didn't understand it, feel

```
free to ask:*
import { oneOfType, string, element, elementType } from 'prop-types';
import { Fragment } from 'react';

// defining test component
function Test({ Element, ElementType }) {
  console.log(ElementType)
  return (
    <ElementType> {/* <--- [*] Note React Component Should be capitalized */}
      Here is Element : {Element}
    </ElementType>
  )
}
// default props for Test
Test.defaultProps = {
  Element: <u>default element</u>,
  ElementType: Fragment

}

// define propTypes for Test
Test.propTypes = {
  Element: oneOfType([string, element]), // <-- you should use oneOfType not oneOf
  ElementType: elementType
}

// define Wrapper component
function Wrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgreen" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}



export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Test />
      <hr />
      <Test ElementType={Wrapper} />
      <hr />
      <Test Element="hi i am element prop (string type)" />
      <hr />
      <Test Element={<b>hi another time (element type)</b>} ElementType={Wrapper} />
    </>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `componentClass` property defined on your component - your prop is called `containerElement` and you should use `oneOfType`:

```
Col.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  containerElement: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.element
  ])
```

Comment: While that is correct, I don't think this will solve the validation problem.

Comment: That was a typo by me.  With the correct name, it still fails validation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Col.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    containerElement: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func
    ]),
}
```

because React components are functions in a global sense, and

```
typeof (class MyClass {}) // => "function"
```