# Adding additional props to a component passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using [React Table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) along with [React Custom Scrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) in a react-redux application. To connect these two I need to override the TbodyComponent in react table such that I can wrap the default tbodycomponent with the scrollbars and pass additional props to tweak rendering. Here's some stripped down code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import {ReactTableDefaults} from 'react-table'
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars'

const TableBody = props => {
    //get additional props beyond just props.children here
    const {autoHeight} = props

    return (
        <Scrollbars 
            style={{
                height: '100vh'
            }}
        >
            <ReactTableDefaults.TbodyComponent>
                 {props.children}
            </ReactTableDefaults.TbodyComponent>
        </Scrollbars>
    )
}


const Table = props => {
    //props stuff would go here

    return (
            <div className="react-table-wrapper">
                <ReactTable {...props}
                            TbodyComponent={TableBody} //this works
                            //TbodyComponent={(props) => {return (<TableBody autoHeight={props.autoHeight} children={props.children} />)}} //this doesn't
                            data={data}
                            columns={columns}
                            ...
                />
            </div>
    )
}
```

I'm guessing I'm not understanding the proper way to pass a component in the TbodyComponent property, props.children, or something along those lines. This method just ends up looping forever.

In this example, how could I get the autoHeight prop to pass?

Update: Experimented with createElement and cloneElement and still receive the 130 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to convert the TableBody stateless component into a full component, that is

```
class TableBody extends React.Component {
```

instead of

```
const TableBody = props => {
```

That's what React-Table was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why this wouldn't work?

```
TbodyComponent={<TableBody autoHeight={props.autoHeight} />}
```

Also, I don't think you need to pass props.children - that should happen by default.

For reference, I looked at the answer provided here to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/8060919

Comment: Tried that and receive the following React error:

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you're doing all of your imports correctly? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. You may be importing components with brackets when you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of react-table you could pass the props via the `getTbodyProps`. It must be a function returning the props as an object.

`<ReactTable TbodyComponent={TableBody} getTbodyProps={()=>({autoHeight})}/>`

[See in the code](https://github.com/TanStack/table/blob/6a9ebf09dab498f61591a9f4f9b15663cbffac63/src/index.js#L193)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<ReactTable TbodyComponent={v => <DropTbody test={null} />}
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.