# render react const as component

Tags: reactjs, render, es6-class

Let say I have this Parent

```
const Parent = () => <ChildComponent foo={<Button>clic</Button>} />
```

why would this code work

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.foo}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

but this code would not ?

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const ParentButton = this.props.foo
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ParentButton />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I need something like the second example in order to add some event to ParentButton.

I'd like to make [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/1317323) work with class defined component

**Update :**

Based on answer I now have a partial solution

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.ParentButton = this.props.foo
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.ParentButton}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning `ParentButton` to the `ChildComponent`.

What you currently have is a `const` floating in the constructor since `const`, `let` and `var` keywords are function/block scoped.

`this. ParentButton = this.props.foo` and succinctly `<this. ParentButton >` in your render function will get you what you're after.

Comment: I mark it as answer for the scope part. as for rendering <this.ParentButton> do not work. (Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.)

Comment: @Yvain Get rid of the `{}` and render it like so `<this.ParentButton />` since it's a component.