# Passing components into another in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an app with a number of components. One of the components I need be to able to pass different variations of another two components into, based on a layout. I believe it can be passed in like a data attribute, but I'm unsure of the exact syntax to push the other components in.

Given two components `<List />` and `<Box />` which are currently in another component being imported into my main `App.js` file as such:

```
export const CallOut = () => {
  return(
      <div style={styles.sectionInner}>
        <List />
        <BoxRight/>
      </div>
  )
};
```

where `<CallOut />` is being imported into `App.js`, I'd like to pass those two components into the `<CallOut />` component.

What is the correct syntax to pass those two in and have them placed in the same spot they're currently in within the `CallOut` component?

I believe it should be something similar to

`<CallOut param={List} param={BoxRight} />`

but I know this isn't right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass react component as props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652686/pass-react-component-as-props)

Answer (score 0):

You can use capital names for props, and use these to instantiate react components like this:

```
export const CallOut = ({List, Box}) => (
  <div style={styles.sectionInner}>
    <List/>
    <Box/>
  </div>
);
```

`List` and `Box` are the properties of this component. You can instantiate it like this:

```
<CallOut List={SomeComponent} Box={SomeOtherComponent}/>
```

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it. However, how can I pass them simply on the `<CallOut />` component so that it's something like `<CallOut list={List} box={BoxRight}/>`

Comment: You can assign these props to variables with names starting with a capital letter and then just use them like any other components.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you mean?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion on what I'm working towards. I'll have multiple instances of `<CallOut />` within the layout, and need to pass different variations of the `<List />` and `<Box />` components into the `<CallOut />` component which lies within the App.js main file. So there would be `<CallOut list={listone} box={boxLeft} />` and variations like that.

Comment: With this code, you can pass `List` and `BoxRight` as properties.

Comment: However, that hardcodes the variations to the `CallOut` component. The CallOut needs to be able to have different variations of the list and box components passed into `<CallOut />`, and the CallOut component function would just be a wrapper of sorts.

Comment: I think I was getting the idea of passing values from one component to another mixed up with passing a component variant into another component, though I thought you could pass a component as a prop such as `<CallOut listLeft={this.props.listLeft} boxTop={this.props.boxTop} />`. Is there not a way to pass components as a prop? Thanks for your continued help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we're on the same page but maybe you're looking for [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) property ?

So your component will look like that:

```
export const CallOut = ({children}) => (
  <div style={styles.sectionInner}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

And usage:

```
  <CallOut >
    <List/>
    <Box/>
  </CallOut>
```

You can pass any component as `CallOut` child or even do some filtering using [children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

It's common usage when components don’t know their children ahead of time and it's used just for some kind of boxing/wrapping.

Comment: This is the same implementation that DoMiNeLa10 initially posted before changing to the current version. I'm looking for a way to pass `List` and `Box` as values into `CallOut` as something like `<CallOut list={props.List} box={props.Box} />` There will be multiple `CallOut` components with variations of the list and box components passed into them. Hopefully this helps clear up the confusion. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, i got it. So maybe pass functions which will be called to create list and box components inside your `CallOut` component. It will look like that:
`<CallOut list={() => <List someProp={1}/>} box={() => <Box someProp={1}/> }/>`. Is it what your are looking for ?