# IntrinsicElements typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

`const Hashable: React.SFC<{Element: string}> = 
    ({ Element = 'div', ...props }) => <Element {...props} id={'someId'} />`

ts error: Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

How do I type the props (id) for the intrinsic element?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/266535

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866429/266535