# React Passing Const Function Around

Tags: reactjs

I am calculating time in App.js and passing it to the child to just display. I know none of this makes sense, but I am practicing learning how to create const and send over to child then accept from child and print on the page. This example works but I assume there is a better way to do this than what I did here, isn't it?

App.js

```
const Time = () => {
  const dateBirth = moment('19010522', 'YYYYMMDD')
  const dateNow = moment()
  const difference = dateNow.diff(dateBirth, "years")
  return (
    <div>{difference}</div>
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const date = <Time />;
    return (
      <div>
        <Person Time={date} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Person.js

```
export default function Person({ Time }) {
  return (
    <span>
        Time: {Time}
    </span>
  )
}
```

Also I tried to send it like below, it didn't work. Why?

```
<Person Time={Time} />
```

Comment: For more reading, consider checking out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652686/pass-react-component-as-props).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it by using `<Person Time={Time} />`, then your person component should look like this:

```
export default function Person({ Time }) {
  return (
    <span>
        Time: <Time />
    </span>
  )
}
```