# pass component as prop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought it was simple but looks like I´m doing something wrong

```
const name = "Mike"
...
<MyComponent
    data={
        <Picture /> + " " + name
    }
/>

const Picture () => return <img src="..." />

const myComponent (props) => return props.data
```

i´m getting this output

```
[object Object] Mike
```

thank you!

Comment: What is `user.name` used for?

Comment: try this:

`return <div>{props.data}</div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass react component as props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652686/pass-react-component-as-props)

Answer (score 4):

You should separate the passing of both items into 2 different props, rather than joining them together (they are both different types - `ReactNode`, and `string`). The advantage of doing so is that there will be better type checking, especially if you are using `TypeScript` or `PropTypes`.

```
<MyComponent
  data={<Picture />}
  name={user.name}
/>
```

Then in the myComponent itself, you should do this if you are trying to print the name under the `Picture`.

```
const myComponent = ({ data, name }) => (
  <>
    {data}
    {name}
  </>
);
```

Comment: don't forget `react.cloneElement(data)`

Comment: yeah. wanted to avoid to pass a second component. but ... if is not possible then I will give up :)

Comment: @Chiller you shouldn't use `cloneElement` if you're not going to change anything on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const Picture = () => <img alt="" src="" />;
const MyComponent = props => props.data;

export default function App() {
  return (
    const user = ...
    <MyComponent
      data={
        <>
          <Picture />
          {user.name}
        </>
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Any value should be passed thru `{your value}`

```
{user.name}
```

In this part of code, you shouldn't use return `const MyComponent = props => props.data;`

If you wanna return it in classic way write like this:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    return props.data
};
```

Comment: While the other answers are not wrong, this is the only one that really demonstrates how to pass arbitrary JSX to a component prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example:

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ChildComp} from "./ChildComp";
import {Hello} from "./Hello";

export class ParentComp extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComp>
                    <Hello/>
                </ChildComp>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export class ChildComp extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Hello Component**

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export class Hello extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a component as a prop. However, look at this line:

```js
<Picture /> + " " + user.name
```

Since `<AnyComponent />` results in a React **element**, and a React element is internally represented as an object, you're essentially doing this:

```js
{} + " " + user.name
```

which is why you're seeing `[object Object]` in your output. What you should do is

```js
function MyComponent({ pictureElement, name }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {pictureElement} {name}
    </div>
  );
}
```