# How to add JSX inside props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component which has `props` value. This component is global and I don't want to change its source code.
I want to add `pre` tag inside the value prop to have a proper indentation between `title` and `value`.

```
<component
   title = {<strong>Name</strong>}
   value = {<pre>  {name === undefined ? myName : myNames}</pre>}
/>
```

Issue: I get **NaN** for value prop. 
How do I fix it?

Also, is there a way to add a gap/padding between `title` and `value`? Please note that I do not wish to modify the source file of `Component`.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652686/pass-react-component-as-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I face a situation like this, my first approach is to make a helper function to render the smaller parts and pass them as props while invoking that function simultaneously.

For instance, for your case:-

```js
//helper function to render title
const renderTitle = () => {
    return <strong>Name</strong>;
 };
//helper function to render value, you can also add styles to them via inline styles or using class or id.
const renderValue = () => {
  return (
    <pre style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
      {name === undefined ? "myName" : "myNames"}
    </pre>
  );
};
return (
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <CustomComponent title={renderTitle()} value={renderValue()} />
    // invoking the helper functions to render the title and value
  </div>
);
```

Codesandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-resonance-h4m49

Answer (score 1):

You can pass prop Components in that following Example what I made for live view you can check here **[SandBox](https://playcode.io/818340/)**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Success = () => {
  return <pre>Your state isn't undefined</pre>
}

const Undefined = () => {
  return <pre>Your state isn't undefined</pre>
}

const ReturnProp = ({propJSX}) => {
  return propJSX
} 

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(undefined)

  return <ReturnProp propJSX={name===undefined? <Undefined />: <Success />}/>
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```