# Proper way of passing function from one component to other on React typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I am new to typescript, I was facing problems while passing the function of the parent component as a prop to another component, I searched online but nothing was useful

For reference, I am attaching JSX Code here, [TSX is what I wish]

This is parent component

```
export default function Notification() {
    const [notification, setnotification] = useState(['alert', 'booking'])

    return (
        <div>
            <ShowNotification setnotification={setnotification} notification={notification} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is child component

```
const ShowNotification = ({notification,setnotification}) => {
    notification.map((item, index) => {
        <li>item</li>
    })
}
```

The main issue for me is specifying prop types in typescript

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652686/pass-react-component-as-props), which may help you.

But in summary, It's same as like passing other normal props.

Here is the basic example which may help you to understand:

```
// button.tsx
interface IProps {
  children: React.FC | string;
  onClick: (e: any) => void;
  type: "button" | "reset";
}

const Button: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <button type={props.type} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

```
import Button from "./button";

export default function App() {
  const myFunction = (e: any) => {
    console.log("Event is: ", e);
  };

  return (
    <Button type="button" onClick={myFunction}>
      Click Me
    </Button>
  );
}
```

In here, you can see, I've passed the `myFunction` to the `Button` component as a props, and call that method from the `Button`Component itself, Whenever someone press the button, it execute the `myFunction` method from the parent `App.tsx` file.

Comment: what will be the modification in above code if I want to pass state

Comment: you can simply pass the state with some name `<Button name={stateValue}>` and use it in your child component.

Comment: @SanketPatil can you please accept this answer, so in future other can easily read it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Basically it is simple:

```
let my_function = () => {console.log('hi!')}
```

you just have to pass it as an argument:

```
return (
<>
<MyAnotherComponent my_function={my_function}></MyAnotherComponent>
</>
)
```

and inside `MyAnotherComponent` you can call it like:

```
props.my_function()
```