# How to pass function into React child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent `Container`, I plan to pass inside different child components that will accept callback.

Container:

```
const Container = ({children}) => {
   const [selection, setSelection] = useState([]);

   const setSelection = (returnObject) => {
      setSelection(prev => [...selection, returnObject])
   }

   return(
      <StyledContainer>
         {children}
         <Button>Search {selection}</Button>
      </StyledContainer>
   )
}
```

Container will have different children that all accept callback:

```
<Container><Child1 callback={}></Container>
<Container><Child2 callback={}></Container>
<Container><Child3 callback={}></Container>
```

Is there a way to pass component as a child to `Container` and for that `Child` to be using `setSelection` function as prop for `Child`'s `callback` prop? (without Redux)

Comment: `setSelection` having a function with same name as state update function will lead to an error.

Comment: First of all, your react code is incorrect. You have `setSelection` coming from `useState` then you are defining a const with same name `setSelection` on the next line, that is invalid code.

Comment: This issue has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children 

You can refer to this. I hope this resolves your query.

Comment: You can pass components as children, react components accept children as  props and you can access the children as `props.children` in your parent component. Here's a StackOverflow answer for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/13901135](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655113/13901135)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can override any props passed to the children as follows:

```
const Container = ({children}) => {
   const [selection, setSelection] = useState([]);

   const setSelection = (returnObject) => {
      setSelection(prev => [...selection, returnObject])
   }

   return(
      <StyledContainer>
         {React.cloneElement(children, {callback: setSelection } }
         <Button>Search {selection}</Button>
      </StyledContainer>
   )
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
<Container><Child1/></Container>
<Container><Child2/></Container>
<Container><Child3/></Container>
```

And inside of each `Child` component, you can call `callback()` as need it.

`React.cloneElement` will create a copy from `children` passing additional props in this case only `callback` is passed as a prop you can pass as many as you need as a new object.

Details: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement