# Pass a wrapper component as props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a wrapper component as props. Is something like this technically possible in React?

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ChildComp from './child-comp';

class Comp extends Component {
  render() {
    const { Wrapper } = this.props;
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <ChildComp />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

Comp.propTypes = {};

export default Comp;
```

Comment: Props Proxy [Higher order components](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.aosc7lsuy) may be what you are looking for. Basically a wrapping function that passing the component around.

Comment: HOC Documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1185/components/4649/creating-components#t=20161223100405611594

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible, and commonly used. The only thing is, as a convention, in JSX capitalized words mean a user defined component, so you'll need to have your properties lowercased and you must capitalize the variable used to hold the component's reference.

```
import React from 'react';

function HelloWorld () {
  return (
    <span>
      <Foo wrapper={Bar}/>
      <Foo wrapper="h5"/>
    </span>
  );
}

class Bar extends  React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // the variable name must be capitalized
    const Wrapper = this.props.wrapper;
    return (
      <Wrapper><p>This works!</p></Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

For native components you can pass a String, like so: `<Foo wrapper="h1"/>`. This works because JSX is just a syntax sugar for `React.createElement('h1',props, children)`

Comment: Great answer! is it going to work if Wrapper is not a react component, but just a native HTML div?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd pass a native component, one solution that works is a functional component `<Foo wrapper={({children}) => (<h1>{children}</h1>)}/>`

Comment: Found a better way, I added to my answer.

Comment: Can I add a className to h1?

Comment: In the `Wrapper` yes, `Wrapper className="foo"` but directly in the place you're passing it as a prop, no. You can pass another prop to use as the `className` for this component.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap components in a number of ways.  However, the most common are:

1. Render children

When rendering children, the jsx explicitly uses the wrapping component:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Child />
</Wrapper>
```

and the `Wrapper` component looks like:

```
export default class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. Higher order component

A higher order component (HOC), is a way to mixin functionality without necessarily changing the jsx markup.  You can change the jsx, but you can also mixin functionality without changing the jsx.

Using the HOC looks like this:

```
const Wrapped = Wrapper(Child);

...

<Wrapped />
```

And the HOC itself would look like:

```
export default Child => class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/keshav1706/pen/eWMZwL?editors=0010

here's a codepen for simple solution.
`

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Component One</h1>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h4>hello</h4>
    )
  }
}
class ComponentThree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h4>component three</h4>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <ComponentOne> <ComponentThree/></ComponentOne>
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`