# How to organize one React component with different wrapper components?

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure

I need some ideas for a folder structure/mental model in React.

I have an `Item` component. It stays the same.
It can be wrapped in either a `Link` with a URL prop or a `Button` with an onClick prop.

My current folder structure solution looks like this:

```
-Item
  -wrapperComponents
    -Link
    -Button
```

Both the Link and Button components wrap around the children prop. Much like this:

```
react stuff ...

return(
  <button onClick={props.handleOnClick}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
)
```

And this is how I call them:

```
<Button>
  <Item />
</Button>

or

<Link>
  <Item />
</Link>
```

I am looking for a better, more elegant solution.

I've tried sending the wrapper components to the `Item` but React doesn't allow to use them as a wrapper that would take children.

Comment: Are you looking at improving the way you call them? What would look elegant to you?

Comment: so i think this is what you are looking for https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/08/compound-components-react/

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz I am looking for the reverse logic of a Compound Component. While with Compound Components you call the parent and their nested children, I need a way to only call the child and from it to choose a parent.

Comment: in that case what you can do is something like passing the Wrapper Component as Prop and using it like this:

<Wrapper>
 your item component
</Wrapper>

Comment: <Item wrapperComponent={<Button onClick={}/>}

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz sadly this doesn't work. As I mentioned in the post sending the Wrapper component in the props and wrapping it around the child crashes React.

I can send a component that doesn't wrap around without any issues but one that wraps around and displays children breaks React.

Comment: can you please send that specific component I can help you fix it.

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz I don't have it. I've scrapped the work yesterday. I've tried to use the solution from over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299203/pass-a-wrapper-component-as-props-in-reactjs but it doesn't work. React crashes.

Comment: Ha! Strange thing is, I tried to replicate the problem to show you the issue and it works. https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-wlmkyv?file=/src/components/Item.jsx

I'll try to solve this in a future reference. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with this solution with the help you you guys

https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-wlmkyv?file=/src/App.js

Main component `App.js`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper";
import Item from "./components/Item";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Item wrapper={Wrapper} wrapperProps={{ color: "orange" }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Item component `Item.js`:

```
import * as React from "react";

function Item(props) {
  const Wrapper = props.wrapper;
  const wrapperProps = props.wrapperProps;

  return (
    <Wrapper {...wrapperProps}>
      <div>An Item</div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

Wrapper component `Wrapper.js`:

```
import * as React from "react";

function Wrapper(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.color || "red" }}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Item from "./Item";
import Wrapper1 from "./Wrapper1";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Item wrapper={Wrapper1} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Item component:

```
const Item = ({ wrapper: Wrapper }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div>This is my child</div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper1 = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      This is my wrapper
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper1;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-vaughan-4op2l1?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added one that handles the props too. I'm really happy when the community comes up with solutions together.