# How to pass a React component as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using react-semantic-ui Modal object.
The object that opens the modal is a prop.

```
 <Modal
       trigger=<Button>Text</Button>
       otherProp=...
   >
  </Modal>
```

I want to embed Modal in another component:

```
export default class Confirm extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                trigger={this.props.trigger} /* here */
              >    
                <Modal.Content>
                    ...
                </Modal.Content>
                <Modal.Actions>
                    ...
                </Modal.Actions>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I pass JSX code ( `<Button>Text</Button>` ) as a prop to be render as a Modal prop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the)

Answer (score 21):

You can easily do following

```
<Modal trigger={ <Button>Text</Button> }> 
   // content goes here 
</Modal>
```

and inside `Modal`, you can access it via `this.props.trigger` which will be your button component and you can render it like below

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            // some code can go here
            { this.props.trigger }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is how can I render `this.props.trigger` in the Modal tag definition.  I want to pass `<Button>Text</Button>` as a prop

Comment: Hi @znat, I have answered already ;), you can print it in `Modal` like any other string prop or variable. `{ this.props.trigger }` in your `render` method

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding: I need something like that: 
    <Modal trigger={this.props.trigger}> 
       // content goes here 
    </Modal>
But this doesn't work