# ReactJS - Passing components and elements as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `Tabs` component that allows you customize some parts of the layout through properties.

For example, you can have a custom layout for the *New Tab Button* or for what's rendered by default when you open a new Tab.

On the first case, the `Tabs` component can receive a `Component` class / function as a prop called `customTabComponent` that will be used to create each `Tab` element:

```
<Tabs customComponent={MyCustomComponent} ... />
```

However, on the second case, the content would be always the same, so `Tabs` could receive a React's element as property instead of a component:

```
render () {
    const defaultContent = <DefaultTabContent prop1={x} prop2={y}/>
    return (
       <Tabs defaultTabContent={defaultContent} ... />
    )    
}
```

Does it make sense to pass an `Element` as prop instead of a `Component`? If yes, `Tabs` component would use this element for every new tab. Should the `Tabs` component clone the passed element for each new Tab?

Comment: why not use children components instead?

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the