# react Intl - how to get value from formattedMessage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-intl

I have a component that takes a number. 
`<ClickableNumber num={num} />`

I'm getting this number from my language pack with a FormattedMessage
 `<ClickableNumber num={<FormattedMessage id="native_number" />} />`

when I console log `num` inside `ClickableNumber` it is an object.

How do I get the string or number version of the value from `<FormattedMessage id="native_number" />`?

I can get the value if I used `intl.formatMessage({ id: 'native_number' })` but I'm trying to reuse the `ClickableNumber` and do not want to wrap each component that uses this component in `injectIntl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the)

Comment: @jmargolisvt I think this is pretty specific to react-intl library

Comment: "I'm getting this number from my language pack with a FormattedMessage". It would deffinetely help If you showed where this number is coming from.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use the react-intl api to format the number yourself instead of using the component https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatnumber.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used react-intl so I don't know if its gonna work or not but it should work in concept.

What you can do is that create a utility function that will return the desired result. For this situation `intl.formatMessage({ id: 'native_number' })` and the formatted Component.

```
const getNativeNumber = () => {
   // I don't know how but you can get the number here
   // something like
   const nativeNumber = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'native_number' });
   return {
     component: <FormattedMessage id="native_number" />,
     nativeNumber: nativeNumber
   }
}

<ClickableNumber num={getNativeNumber()} />

console.log(this.props.num.nativeNumber)  // This will have the native number in your ClickableNumber component.
```