# React: pass Component as prop and use it with additional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a general component such as this

```js
const Img = ({ component }) => {
  const image_ref = useRef()

  return (
  <>
    {component
      ref={image_ref}
    }
  </>
  )
}
```

And I want to use it with other components like these

```js
const MyImg = () => <Img component={<MySpecificImg />} />
const MyBackImg = () => <Img component={<MySpecificBackImg />} />
```

Is there any way to do this?

The need is to be able to change the component that the `<Img/>` component calls

Comment: You may give a try at HOC components.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42847399/5648954) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371612/5648954)

Comment: @ManirajSS with HOC I can't use useRef or useState since the function is not a component (AFAIU) so I think I can't use it ||| I want to avoid any class-related React here

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks :) first answer doesn't allow me to add more props to the component, so if this is true I can't use this, and second answer uses cloneElement which is something I don't like here, it has to be a simpler solution

Comment: I understand that a HOC could do it, as said in an answer from your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757397/826815 so I'll answer yes, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 7):

If you are passing the prop as `<MySpecificBackImg />`, then you are passing in a JSX element, you can render it in `Img` component as:

```
const Img = ({ element }) => {
  const image_ref = useRef()
  const elementWithRef = React.cloneElement(element, { ref: image_ref });
  return (
  <>
    {element}
  </>
  )
}
```

If you are passing in the component, which you can easily do from the sample:

```
const Img = ({ component: Component }) => {
  const image_ref = useRef()
  return (
  <>
    <Component ref={image_ref} />
  </>
  )
}
```

Do note that the `ref` in both cases is being attached to the outer element, if this is a component instance, you would have to use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to forward it to the inner DOM element.

Comment: By "passing in" you mean as children? *I'm trying to avoid the `cloneElement` and looking at HOC instead / if that's an option

Comment: *At the end I am/I've extracted the redundant logic of the different components into a custom useHook so that now I don't need to change the component (and therefore to use cloneElement)