# How to pass custom prop to a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to react and this is a problem I am trying to solve.

There is a parent component ***parent*** which passes props to the child.
One of these props, include an element to be rendered like this:

```
<child componentToBeRendered = {component} />
```

In the child, I want to take this component and pass a prop to it, which is defined in the child itself.

```
function child(props){
    function toBePassed(){ ... }
    <props.componentToBeRendered fun = {toBePassed} />
}
```

I know that the above code is wrong and we cannot use `<props.componentToBeRendered>`. So how can I pass a custom prop to this component?

The only way I can think of rendering the component is like: `{props.componentToBeRendered};`

How do I render this component with a custom prop defined in the child?

Comment: you need to create a HOC component, Please Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the passed component prop, render it as per usual, and pass props to it as per usual. Similar to [Choosing the Type as Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
function Child(props){
    const ComponentToBeRendered = props.componentToBeRendered;

    function toBePassed(){ ... }

    return <ComponentToBeRendered fun={toBePassed} />;
}
```

I've usually used this pattern with prop destructuring in the function signature, renaming the destructured prop.

```
function Child({ componentToBeRendered: ComponentToBeRendered }) {
  function toBePassed(){ ... }

  return <ComponentToBeRendered fun={toBePassed} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use React's top-level API, specifically `React.createElement`, for instance:

```
const MyChild1 = ({ num }) => <div>num1: {num}</div>;
const Parent = ({ comp }) => 
  <div>
    {React.createElement(comp, { num: 5 })}
    {React.createElement(comp, { num: 1 })}
  </div>
;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you shouldn't pass the component as a prop
Instead pass a value to the child that indicates the component to be rendered.

```
function Parent(){
   return <Child toBeRendered="contact"/>
}
```

```
function Child(props){
   let toBeRenderd;
   switch(props.toBeRendered){
      case 'contact' :
          toBeRendered = Contact;
      default :
          toBeRendered = Info
   }
   return <toBeRendered/>
}
```

Comment: `toBeRendered` isn't a valid react component name. This approach is ok if the set of components is small and manageable, but doesn't cover well if *any* component is allowed to be passed and rendered (think an arbitrary set of icon components where there could be hundreds). This won't scale well at all.