# Dispatching components via react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I want to pass a component and display it inside another one through redux.
I am doing something like this:

> ComponentToDispatch.js

```
const ComponentToDispatch = (props) => {
    return (<div>Propagate me {props.anthem}</div> {/* props.anthem = undefined, unlike what I expect.*/}
);
};
export {ComponentToDispatch};
```

In the following component, I have a button that dispatches the formerly defined one.

> BruitEvent.js

```
 // code above
`import {ComponentToDispatch} from "./ComponentToDispatch";
 import {showComponentAction} from "./actions";
 const BruitEvent =()=>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (<button onClick={(evt)=>dispatch(showComponentAction(ComponentToDispatch)}>
 Click to dispatch</button>);
 };`
```

> The action that triggers this event is:
> actions.js

```
 `
 export function ShowComponentAction(Component) {

 return {
    type: SHOW_ACTION,
    payload: {
      component: <Component />,
  },
 };
}`
```

> Finally, I can display the propagated component:

```
const DispayComponent = () =>{
const { component} = useSelector((state) => {
if (state.testDisplay) {
  return {
    component: state.testDisplay.component,
  };
}
   return { component: null };
 });

useInjectReducer({ key: "testDisplay", reducer });

   return (<div>{component}</div>);
 }
 export {DisplayComponent};
```

So far so good, thanks to David Hellsing [for his insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25807416/3741686), I can display every static thing resides in `ComponentToDispatch', but it fails to handle props.

### Question: How can I transmit props while dispatching component itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either instantiate and enclose the props ***before*** the component is dispatched, or pass the uninstantiated component and props object in the dispatched action and pass the props to the component on the receiving end. I suggest the latter, send both component and props in action.

```
const BruitEvent =()=>{
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={(evt) => dispatch(
        showComponentAction(ComponentToDispatch, /* some possible props object */)
      )}
    >
      Click to dispatch
    </button>
  );
};

...

export function ShowComponentAction(Component, props = {}) {
  return {
    type: SHOW_ACTION,
    payload: { Component, props }, // <-- assumes reducer places in state.testDisplay
  },
};

...

const DispayComponent = () =>{
  const { Component, prop } = useSelector((state) => state.testDisplay);

  useInjectReducer({ key: "testDisplay", reducer });

  return Component ? <div><Component {...props} /></div> : null;
}
```

Comment: I went for instantiating the components before dispatch, but it wasn't the method I was looking for. Your second suggestion is what I need.