# How can insert content component in Layout component in react

Tags: reactjs, layout, components

```
export default function Layout({ prop, title, subTitle, item }) {
  return (
    <LayoutContainer>
      <LayoutMain>
        <MainRow>
          <MainSubTitle>{subTitle}</MainSubTitle>
          <MainTitle>{title}</MainTitle>
          <MainText>
            우리는 모두 모여 춤을 추지. Let's get it.
          </MainText>
        </MainRow>
      </LayoutMain>
      <FixNav />
      {/*여기는 고정 네비게이션 바*/}
      <LayoutContents>{/*I want to insert content*/}</LayoutContents>
    </LayoutContainer>
  );
}
```

{/*This is content component*/}

```
export default function Process() {
  return (
    <Layout title="제조공정" subTitle="df">
      ???
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

I made Layout component, I want to use this component in many different content. For example, I want to build four contents in website. This layout is same. Without rewriting respectively.

please tell me How insert component fluidly.
Thank you..!

Comment: Wrap your `Layout` around the root component that you want to apply, just like you already did with the `LayoutContainer`

Comment: Try to use the props `children`

Comment: That's really good answer! Thank you!

Comment: That's really good answer! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the)

Answer (score 1):

It's the `children` property

```
export default function Layout({ prop, children, title, subTitle, item }) {
  return (
    <LayoutContainer>
      <LayoutMain>
        <MainRow>
          <MainSubTitle>{subTitle}</MainSubTitle>
          <MainTitle>{title}</MainTitle>
          <MainText>
            우리는 모두 모여 춤을 추지. Let's get it.
          </MainText>
        </MainRow>
      </LayoutMain>
      <FixNav />
      {/*여기는 고정 네비게이션 바*/}
      <LayoutContents>{children}</LayoutContents>
    </LayoutContainer>
  );
}
```