# Unwrap a div in react, something similar to jQuery unwrap method

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, unwrap

I am using React JSX. I have a div with className="shadow" as shown below.

```
<div className="main">
  <div className="shadow" style={{backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}}>
    <div id="wrapper">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Based on a certain condition being true or false, I want to remove the div with className="shadow", but want to keep every div including the div with id="wrapper" intact. Something like unwrap() method of jQuery.
Something to the effect of what is written below, but without so many lines of code.

```
  if ( currentPage==="login") {
   <div className="main">
     <div id="wrapper">
       Hello
     </div>
   </div>
}
else {
    <div className="main">
  <div className="shadow" style={{backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}}>
    <div id="wrapper">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

I checked [React.js: Wrapping one component into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851533/react-js-wrapping-one-component-into-another) and [How to pass in a react component into another react component to transclude the first component's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797048/how-to-pass-in-a-react-component-into-another-react-component-to-transclude-the?noredirect=1&lq=1), but didn't get what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what can help you is to change the `className` based on the page you are on, because what you try to do would be better using `react-router` to display different components based on the path you are on.

Use something similar to this code, I hope I can help you.

```js
const App = React.createClass({
  changePage(nextPage) {
    this.setState({ page: nextPage })
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return({
      page: 'Login'
    })
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="main">
        <div className={ this.state.page === 'Login' ? 'shadow' : '' }>
          <div id="wrapper">
            Hello from { this.state.page } page.
          </div>
          <button onClick={ this.changePage.bind(null, 'Login') }>Go to Login page.</button>
          <button onClick={ this.changePage.bind(null, 'Home') }>Go to Home page.</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
div.shadow{ background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: I guess this method won't let me remove the div with class "shadow" from the dom when current page is not login. It will just add/remove the class "shadow" from that div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)!

```
const HOC = (currentPage, Shadow, Wrapper) => (
  () => <div className="main">
    {
      currentPage === 'login'
        ? <Shadow {...this.props} />
        : <Shadow {...this.props}><Wrapper {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Wrapper></Shadow>
    }
  </div>
)
```

Usage:

```
render () {
  const Shadow = props => <div className="shadow" style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}>{props.children}</div>
  const Wrapper = props => <div id="wrapper">Hello</div>

  const Example = HOC(
    currentPage,
    Shadow,
    Wrapper
  )

  return (
    <Example />
  )
}
```

Update:

To render the children of `<Wrapper />`, use `{this.props.children}` and use the `class` syntax in HOC:

```
const HOC = (currentPage, Shadow, Wrapper) => (
  class extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div className="main">
          {
            currentPage === 'login'
              ? <Shadow />
              : <Shadow><Wrapper>{this.props.children}</Wrapper></Shadow>
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

If you needed to capture `props` on `<Shadow />` and `<Wrapper />`, then do something like the following.  Note: I don't think you can pass props into normal DOM elements like `<div>` tags. But if they were other components with a Capital starting letter, then I believe passing props through with `{...this.props}` would work nicely.

```
const HOC = (currentPage, Shadow, Wrapper) => (
  class extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div className="main">
          {
            currentPage === 'login'
              ? <Shadow {...this.props} />
              : <Shadow {...this.props}><Wrapper {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Wrapper></Shadow>
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This solution seemed to work for me. But, unfortunately instead of "Hello" inside div with id "wrapper", I have <Content currentPage={currentPage}  />. This Content component returns different components based on "currentPage". So, somewhere it is getting lost in an infinite loop and never rendering the desired result. Only <Content/> is fine, but Content with currentPage as its props is causing problems, but even I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @abhi, Updated.  You can render `<Wrapper />`'s children with `{this.props.children}`. Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: it is still behaving the same way, never rendering the content on the page. So, I decided to go the traditional way using if else conditional rendering.

Comment: @abhi, I have tested the code in my answer and know that it works.  Please verify that you are 1) using the class syntax as outlined in my previous update and 2) are using `{this.props.children}` in your `render ()` method.

Comment: Yes I am using class syntax as well as {this.props.children} in my render method. I can't post my complete code here, but I guess somewhere in my long complicated code, it gets lost and fails to render.